# in item in string.xml i m passing url and url contaiins symbol & it is giving error

Tags: android, xml

this is my array there is a & symbol and it is giving error 
and when i give & the url wont load the image
so i want to load the image via item usuing url

```
    <resources>
<string name="app_name">IYCC</string>

<string name="navigation_drawer_open">Open navigation drawer</string>
<string name="navigation_drawer_close">Close navigation drawer</string>
<string name="action_settings">Settings</string>

<!-- TODO: Remove or change this placeholder text -->
<string name="hello_blank_fragment">Hello blank fragment</string>

<array name="images_array">
    <item>http://cp1.biz.ht/beta/file-manager/downloadFile?filePath=%2Fimzzycool.biz.ht%2FPhotoUpload%2Fuploads%2F43.png&amp;fileName=43.png</item>
    <item>http://cp1.biz.ht/beta/file-manager/downloadFile?filePath=%2Fimzzycool.biz.ht%2FPhotoUpload%2Fuploads%2F43.png&amp;fileName=43.png</item>
    <item>http://cp1.biz.ht/beta/file-manager/downloadFile?filePath=%2Fimzzycool.biz.ht%2FPhotoUpload%2Fuploads%2F43.png&amp;fileName=43.png</item>
    <item>http://cp1.biz.ht/beta/file-manager/downloadFile?filePath=%2Fimzzycool.biz.ht%2FPhotoUpload%2Fuploads%2F43.png&amp;fileName=43.png</item>
    <item>http://cp1.biz.ht/beta/file-manager/downloadFile?filePath=%2Fimzzycool.biz.ht%2FPhotoUpload%2Fuploads%2F43.png&amp;fileName=43.png</item>
    <item>http://cp1.biz.ht/beta/file-manager/downloadFile?filePath=%2Fimzzycool.biz.ht%2FPhotoUpload%2Fuploads%2F43.png&amp;fileName=43.png</item>
    <item>http://lh6.ggpht.com/_ZN5zQnkI67I/TCFFZaJHDnI/AAAAAAAABVk/YoUbDQHJRdo/s144-c/P9250508.JPG</item>
</array>

<array name="headline_array">
    <item>image 1</item>
    <item>image 2</item>
    <item>image 3</item>
    <item>image 4</item>
    <item>image 5</item>
    <item>image 6</item>
    <item>image 7</item>
</array>
```

Comment: show us some more code

Comment: use ascii in xml resources. http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm

Comment: that is the code will show u the full code of string.xml

Comment: ankit popli i tried that too but as it is a url it is not working that way

Comment: Might be worth reading about the HTML styling section here.  https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#FormattingAndStyling

Answer (score 0):

How about doing it like this?

```
<array name="images_array">
    <item path="http://cp1.biz.ht/beta/file-manager/downloadFile?filePath=%2Fimzzycool.biz.ht%2FPhotoUpload%2Fuploads%2F43.png&fileName=43.png">
    <item path="http://lh4.ggpht.com/_4f1e_yo-zMQ/TCe5h9yN-TI/AAAAAAAAXqs/8X2fIjtKjmw/s144-c/IMG_1786.JPG">
    <item path="http://lh3.ggpht.com/_GEnSvSHk4iE/TDSfmyCfn0I/AAAAAAAAF8Y/cqmhEoxbwys/s144-c/_MG_3675.jpg">
    <item path="http://lh6.ggpht.com/_ZN5zQnkI67I/TCFFZaJHDnI/AAAAAAAABVk/YoUbDQHJRdo/s144-c/P9250508.JPG">
    <item path="http://lh4.ggpht.com/_XjNwVI0kmW8/TCOwNtzGheI/AAAAAAAAC84/SxFJhG7Scgo/s144-c/0014.jpg">
    <item path="http://lh6.ggpht.com/_Nsxc889y6hY/TBp7jfx-cgI/AAAAAAAAHAg/Rr7jX44r2Gc/s144-c/IMGP9775a.jpg">
    <item path="http://lh6.ggpht.com/_ZN5zQnkI67I/TCFFZaJHDnI/AAAAAAAABVk/YoUbDQHJRdo/s144-c/P9250508.JPG">
</array>
```

Comment: "" wont work the error will be still there tried that too

Answer (score 0):

<s>Replace your '&' symbols with</s>

```
"&amp;"
```

This is an acceptable usage and works when making requests

I just realized you're using

```
<array>
```

and not

```
<string-array>
```

Comment: any solution for the above mentioned problem

Comment: I thought you said you changed your &s to "&amp;"?

Comment: i have problem with & it is in url

Comment: The only issue I can see right now is using a generic array instead of string-array. Can you post your code for handling a URL?